# 'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Are using the SonarQube sonar.testExecutionReportPaths to import test execution

Are using the example from the doc in:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data

Using the example xml from the doc:

```
<testExecutions version="1">
<file path="testx/ClassOneTest.xoo">
<testCase name="test1" duration="5"/>
<testCase name="test2" duration="500">
<skipped message="short message">other</skipped>
</testCase>
<testCase name="test3" duration="100">
<failure message="short">stacktrace</failure>
</testCase>
<testCase name="test4" duration="500">
<error message="short">stacktrace</error>
</testCase>
</file>
</testExecutions>
```

Have only change the path value.

But get this error:

'Generic Coverage Report' skipped because one of the required properties is missing.

What is the reason for this error?

BTW. If I get the tes execution imported where can I see it in SonarQube.

Running SonarQube 6.5 and scanner 3.0.3.778.

Thanks

Comment: Just found this message in the Log:Test execution data ignored for 1 unknown files, including:

Comment: Your file path needs to match the path as the scanner sees it. Is `testx` truly in the root of your project?

Comment: Is it the root of the testcase.xml location or the source locations that needs to be in the testExecutions xml?

Comment: @LarsKaareAndersen did you find a solution to the issue above?

Comment: @LarsKaareAndersen Hi, did you managed to fix the issue?